# How can I get faster render times for a single image?

Tags: rendering, performance

When rendering a single frame, either by pushing <kbd>F12</kbd> or from the **Properties** → **Render** menu, is there any way to speed up the process? I know about rendering animation through the Python console to speed up rendering time, but can this be applied to a single frame of animation?

Comment: Are you asking how to render a single frame from the console?

Comment: dont understand the question, I think you could re-phrase, are you asking how to make a screen-shot?

Comment: Lindsey, the question is in danger of being closed, please clarify exactly what you mean and then 'flag' to reopen. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean to do a quick openGL rendering of your animation like a [playblast animation](https://vimeo.com/17228975)?

Answer (score 5):

there are several possibilities depending of your scene setup and renderer (blender internal [BI] or Cycles), but beware, most of them are lowering your overall quality. But we're faking all of the time in CG, so why not here too ;)

- Reduce the number of subdivisions if you're using one or more subdivision surface modifier
- BI: Reduce the number of mirroring surfaces (if any)
- BI: Reduce the number of area lights and replace them with several spots
- BI: Turn down Anti-Aliasing
- Cycles: Reduce the number of samples
- Cycles: Disable the usage of caustics
- Cycles: Split your scene in different passes and render with a different sample count (less samples for simple passes, more samples for heavy passes)
- Cycles: Disable motion blurring
- Cycles Use the direct light Integrator preset (changes your scene appearance too - be warned)
- Decrease your image resolution...

The possibilities are really countless and depend heavily on your scene - so it's really hard to give a specific answer in your case.

You can save a file with F3 when you're above the rendered image.

Greetings, Thomas