# How can I speed up Blender Cycles render time?

Tags: animation

My problem is that my scene is going to take so long to render that I am questioning if I should even go forward. (PC parts and performance aside) Is there a way to adjust this file to still have it not appear grainy, but not take forever because of sample sizes and Denoising? I've tried so many setting variations that i feel like i'm going in circles at this point. I'll attach a blend file to this so hopefully you guys have more of an idea of what setting i can tweak. I just don't understand why such a low-poly scene would take so long to render a frame.. Thanks in advance for any insights you can offer!

Project File: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50442

Comment: This question almost certainly belongs to blender.se anyway you can disable features. It is well known that just cranking blindly up quality settins will lead to this. In anycase the general answer is usually, no. Send your render to a farm.

Comment: A lot of people don't know it but, cows are really efficient at rendering 3D images.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are rendering so many render layers?

Comment: What does you mean when saying "long"? For example, average render time in Next Gen movie is 3.6 hours. Do you have more? I tested your scene and have 4.7 sec for render frame, it's very fast.

Comment: @Crantisz long is subjective. For many people anything less than realtime is slow simply because they have never taxed their machine. I remember having to have explained how a full on indirect illumination solution is slightly different from a game engines result, and this was 1997-1999. And even if its realtime theres quite many hours of optimisation involved. So by no means self evident, but then again I had a client request whiter pixels for their monitor ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comments i guess? haha

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid noisy renders in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles)

Comment: File is down. -

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1367/30849